# Image object for printing

Tags: c#, system.drawing, system.drawing.imaging

I want to create a **System.Drawing.Image** object. That created with another `Image` object containing a **barcode** and **Text** file. I need to add another text to it and optimize it for printing. But while I was trying to do that using `Graphic` class the image is becoming low quality.

I can print from the original object perfectly
and the text in it appears as text in a PDF printer.

Comment: Use Metafile class for printing as image which will be high quality.